# Python googleapiclient cannot get more than 10 results

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, google-search-console

With this code:

```
import json
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from pprint import pprint as pp

NUM_RESULTS = 11
MY_SEARCH = 'bordben'
MY_API_KEY = '...'
MY_CSE_ID = '...'




def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
    return res['items']

results = google_search(MY_SEARCH, MY_API_KEY, MY_CSE_ID, num=NUM_RESULTS)

for result in results:
    pp(result)
```

if `NUM_RESULTS` greater than 10 I will get an error like this:

```
 googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=bordben&cx=...( api key and csi id)&alt=json returned "Request contains an invalid argument.". Details: "[{'message': 'Request contains an invalid argument.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest'}]">
```

if `NUM_RESULTS = 10` or less than 10, there will print the search results. , why there is a limit by 10?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:

https://gist.github.com/adambernier/0cc96d07691a635cc464d24c63caff39

each API call not be greater then 10 results.